# ValueError: Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() & AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to create a function which could convert some concentrations into nanomolar concentration. So I wrote this function:

```
def convert_molars(df, field_values, field_units):

    if (df[field_units].str.contains('uM')): # 1 uM = 1000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000
    
    elif (df[field_units].str.contains('M')): # 1 M = 1000000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000000
    
    else: # 1 mM = 1000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000
    
    return df
```

And I started it like this:

```
standard_units = convert_molars(IC50_nonan_units, 'Standard Value', 'Standard Units')
standard_units.to_csv("standard_units.csv")
standard_units.head()
```

But I got this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I tried one more option like this:

```
def convert_molars_bool(df, field_values, field_units):

    if (df[field_units].str == 'uM').bool(): # 1 uM = 1000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000
    
    elif (df[field_units].str == 'M').bool(): # 1 M = 1000000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000000
    
    else: # 1 mM = 1000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000
    
    return df
```

But I got this:

```
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'bool'
```

Could someone please explain me that I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `==` operator returns a bool value. In your `if` and `elif` conditions you are trying to run the `bool()` method on a bool.

```py
def convert_molars_bool(df, field_values, field_units):

    if (df[field_units].str == 'uM'): # 1 uM = 1000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000
    
    elif (df[field_units].str == 'M'): # 1 M = 1000000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000000
    
    else: # 1 mM = 1000000 nM
        df[field_values] *= 1000000
    
    return df
```

This should work

Comment: This won't work. `df[field_units].str` returns a `pandas.core.strings.accessor.StringMethods` object which is never going to be equal  to `'uM'`. The only thing this will do is multiply `1000000` onto every row since both conditionals will always be `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df[field_units].str.conatins('uM'), field_values] = 1000*df.loc[df[field_units].str.conatins('uM'), field_values]

df.loc[df[field_units].str.conatins('M'), field_values] = 1000000000*df.loc[df[field_units].str.conatins('M'), field_values]

df.loc[(~df[field_units].str.conatins('M')) & (~df[field_units].str.conatins('uM')), field_values] = 1000000*df.loc[(~df[field_units].str.conatins('M')) & (~df[field_units].str.conatins('uM')), field_values]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what `df[field_units].str.contains('uM')` gives you.
It should be a `pandas` `Series` of `bool`s.

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {
    'Standard Units': ['uM', 'M', 'D'], 
    'Standard Value': [23.34, 245.6, 102]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df['Standard Units'].str.contains('uM'))
#0     True
#1    False
#2    False
#Name: Standard Units, dtype: bool
```

Even if this wouldn't raise an error, `df[field_values] *= 1000` would multiply `1000` onto EVERY row. It doesn't know anything about the conditional in the previous line of code.

What you are trying to do is apply this logic to each row individually rather than the `DataFrame` as a whole.

For this you could use a `for` loop or better, `df.apply()`.

`df.apply` takes a function to apply to each column or row.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {
    'Standard Units': ['uM', 'M', 'D'], 
    'Standard Value': [23.34, 245.6, 102]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

def func(row):
    if 'uM' in row['Standard Units']:
        return row['Standard Value'] * 1000
    elif 'M' in row['Standard Units']:
        return row['Standard Value'] * 1000000000
    else:
        return row['Standard Value'] * 1000000

df['Standard Value'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)

print(df)
#  Standard Units  Standard Value
#0             uM    2.334000e+04
#1              M    2.456000e+11
#2              D    1.020000e+08
```

Or, if you want to keep the same function signature you were using :

```
import pandas as pd
dct = {
    'Standard Units': ['uM', 'M', 'D'], 
    'Standard Value': [23.34, 245.6, 102]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)

def convert_molars(df, field_values, field_units):
    # create a function to apply
    def func(row):
        if 'uM' in row[field_units]:
            return row[field_values] * 1000
        elif 'M' in row[field_units]:
            return row[field_values] * 1000000000
        else:
            return row[field_values] * 1000000
    # apply the function that was just created
    df[field_values] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
    # return the DataFrame
    return df

df = convert_molars(df, 'Standard Value', 'Standard Units')

print(df)
```